# Weblogic notification for restart

Tags: weblogic12c, restart, weblog

How do I track if weblogic needs restart after any datasource or new service changes? Assuming you do not notice the notification displayed by weblogic...

https://images.app.goo.gl/n8eTrycPvMG6w5y69 ignore URL

Answer (score 0):

The WLST function isRestartRequired() determines if a change you made to an MBean attribute requires you to re-start servers in your domain. Take a look at the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/lifecycle/12.2.1.3/wlstg/config_wls.html#GUID-6A791C74-E4AE-4C07-86E3-A7C8FA7BF104).